# how do i enable auto rotate again in android after triggering the on click from button?

Tags: android, rotation, android-orientation, android-fullscreen

i create an sample apps that triger fullscreen with button and auto rotatation enabled triger also fullscreen, but after using auto rotate and if i use a button for triger another orientation change, then after i click the button now my activity canot do auto rotation again from changing the orientation, only button now can changed the modes, the auto rotation cannot be used anymore. How to fixed this?

is it normal?

button resize

```
public void clickResize(View view) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

button fullscreen

```
public void clickFullscreen(View view) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

methods for addflags, clearflags and configurationChanged()

```
private void onFullscreen() {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

private void offFullscreen() {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        onFullscreen();
}           
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            offFullscreen();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have same issue in my app :(

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem and resolved as follows :

Set `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)` after rotation by code:

from :

```
public void clickResize(View view) {
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);}
```

To :

```
public void clickResize(View view) {
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);` to unable auto rotate of your activity

Comment: nope it did not work, the problem is auto rotation is enable and no problem with it using auto rotate switch on, but after rotating if i click another buton to set to landscape mode not using auto rotate after i click the button, the auto rotation is not working anymore.